# postgresql return single row from function after select statement

Tags: postgresql

How can I return single row from postgresql function? What type should I use after `returns`?
These is my code:

```
create or replace function get_perf()
returns ???? as $$  
select task_ext_perf.performance, task_ext_perf.unit from task_ext_perf order by task_ext_perf.tm limit 1; 
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Returns `record`. Or if you return a row of a table, you can directly `returns MyTable`.

Answer (score 5):

Considering a table `User` like this :

```
User
------
id
name
```

You can return a single row of a table with a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function get_user()
RETURNS User AS $$  
  SELECT id, name
  FROM User
  WHERE id = 1
$$
language sql;
```

If you want to return a more elaborated row, you have to return a `record`, with `OUT` parameters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_user(OUT id integer, OUT name character varying, OUT linkedString character varying)
RETURNS record LANGUAGE sql AS $$
 SELECT
   u.id, u.name, ot.string
 FROM Users u
 INNER JOIN OtherTable ot ON ot.user_id = u.id
 WHERE id = 1
$$;
```

Comment: My example was simplified. I need to return several fields from different tables, not just one row from one table.

Comment: @IrS, I added an example with a procedure that returns a `record`.

Comment: How does one return a single row with plpgsql?

Comment: how would you do this if you were using `EXECUTE _sql`?